# Clickable image inside listview

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

How can i have a image inside a listview and when is clicked do something? I can use a image button but the the image will not fill the button.
The image is a trash icon, that when clicked will have to delete the data that is associated to that listview cell.

ListViewLayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="8dp">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtvNome"
    android:text="Nome"
    android:layout_weight="1.5"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnDeleteLv"
    android:src="@drawable/delete"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

ListViewAdapter:

```
public class ListViewAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
    private readonly Activity context;
    private readonly List<Jogador> jogadores;
    public ListViewAdapter(Activity _context, List<Jogador> _jogadores)
    {
        this.context = _context;
        this.jogadores = _jogadores;
    }
    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return jogadores.Count;
        }
    }
    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return jogadores[position].Id;
    }
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var view = convertView ?? context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ListViewLayout, parent, false);
        var lvtxtNome = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtvNome);
        lvtxtNome.Text = jogadores[position].Nome;
        return view;
    }
    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is set a click event in your Adapter class to an image that you want to be clickable.

In your `ListViewAdapter` find the image button like this:

```
var deleteButton = view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.btnDeleteLv);
```

Then set a click event to the same something like this:

```
deletebutton.Click+= HandleTouchEvent;
```

And add its method like follows:

```
private void HandleTouchEvent(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
     //On Click code 
    }
```